# Best practice - having multiple docker-compose files in a repo

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'am currently working on a fullstack web project that consists of the following components:

- Database (MariaDB)
- Frontend (Angular)
- Backend (NodeJS)

Every component should be deployable through docker. For that I have a `Dockerfile` for each of them. I also defined a `docker-compose` in the repository root to deploy all of them together.

```py
# current repo structure
|frontend/
 |src/
 |docker/
  -Dockerfile
  -docker-compose.yml
|backend/
 |src/
 |docker/
  -Dockerfile
  -docker-compose.yml
|database/
 |src/
 |docker/
  -Dockerfile
  -docker-compose.yml
-docker-compose.yml
```

Do you think this is good practice? I am unsure because I think this my current structure is kind of confusing. How do you handle it in similar projects?

Answer (score 3):

`docker-compose` is designed to orchestrate multiple components of a project in one single place: docker-compose file.

In your case, and as m303945 said, you don't need multiple docker-compose files. Indeed, your main `docker-compose.yml` should call the `Dockerfile` of each of your component. This file could contain something like this:

```
services:

  frontend:
    build:
      context: frontend
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile

  backend:
    build:
      context: backend
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile

  database:
    build:
      context: database
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
```

Answer (score 2):

you dont need multiple docker-compose files. if you want to run specific app together, for example only database and backend just run this command.

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-file.yml up -d database backend
```

which database and backend is service name in the docker-compose file.